# overlay image with text btn

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new in bootstrap and I just want to create image then on top of that I have title and a button.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your [positioning](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjdt7STzPjPAhXOyRoKHSqyBeIQFggrMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fde%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FCSS%2FCSS_Positioning&usg=AFQjCNFnza6PLdKpK63MQgf370QIz_-2jg&sig2=e7HX092TK0HFzKRA3JLegg) just was a bit wrong... Your buttons position `bottom: 5rem;` made the button go out of the window. Use `top` instead like you did with your heading:

```css
.block-hero {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.block-hero-img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 420px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.block-hero-headline {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  padding: 1rem;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3rem;
  left: 1rem;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.mybutton {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10rem;
  left: 1rem;
  max-width: 100%;
}
h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row block-hero">
    <img src="https:/placehold.it/600x450" alt="imgHero.alt" class="block-hero-img" />
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
          <h1 class="block-hero-headline">My Heading</h1>
          <a href="#" class="btn mybutton">My button</a>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Andreas.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change a background image from cms. Why use an image tag ?
For example if the image is coming from php you can do something like.

```
<div class="row block-hero" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $imageSource;?>')">
</div>
```

Comment: Don't forget to rate the question :)